# Explode an Excel formula into a formula that relies only on cells that don't refer to other cells

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm looking for a way to unpack an excel formula into a formula that depends only cells that don't refer to other cells.

**Example:** in the spreadsheet below, cell A1 contains the formula "B1 + B2". Meanwhile, cell B1 contains the formula "C1 + D1", while B2 contains the formula "C2 + D2". Cells C1, C2, D1 and D2 are all constants (in this case, the values 1, 2, 3 and 4).

[image: Example Spreadhseet]

**What I want:** I'm looking for a way (either already built into excel, or a user-defined function in VBA), that would function like this:

> **Call:** =ExplodeFormula(A1)
>
> **Returns:** "C1 + D1 + C2 + D2"

Any chance someone can help me out here? Thanks!

(Edit) A few things I think will be needed for this:

1. Some way to distinguish a cell reference in a formula from the functions used in that formula.
2. Some way to distinguish a range reference from a single cell reference (if a cell is referring to a range, like it would in the case of a vlookup, I'd be fine stopping at that level.
3. A way to iterate through the portions of the formula identified in parts 1 and 2 and break them down into simpler chunks that are recursively run through the same process.

Comment: How do you plan to handle something like `=SUM(A:A)` ?

Comment: Does it need to be able to span worksheets?  How about formulas with references to other workbooks?

Comment: In your posted simplistic case you could likely achieve what you want using the `DirectPrecedents` property of the Range object.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to build an Excel formula parser and apply it recursively to the formulas referred to by any references found in the original formula. And watch out for circular and repeated references!

There are a few formula parsers around, see for starters:
http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/popular/excelformulaparsing.html

and as a matter of curiosity: why would you want to do this?

Comment: Good question about why I want to do this. Here's why: I'm tired of waiting 30+ minutes for the data tables in my spreadsheet to calculate. The data tables that Excel uses for "what if" analysis are incredibly slow. My thinking was that by exploding a formula down to its most basic components, I could easily create a sensitivity table that would calculate much faster than the data tables. That's easy enough to do by hand when you have a simple formula. But, if it's a complex analysis, tracing the formula all the way back through is very laborious.

Comment: Data Tables are slow and iterate single-threaded. You can speed them up by a) speeding up the normal XL calculation process b) writing some VBA code that automates the iterative calculation process more efficiently. Contact me offline if you want to explore this further